# Plone: (Archetypes) Make News Item and Event to be folderish

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I see I can use collective.folderishtypes to add new types (folderish) to be used instead of default news item and event. But I want to convert existing news items and events to folderish content types and keep it as simple as possible. Is it possible to override (monkey-patching?) the default types in a simple way (as result to have existing objects with folderish behavior)?

Or what is the good way of solving this issue? I just need existing objects to be solved, too and to have not confusing duplicate content types like: Add new News Item, News Item Folderish... etc. Also, if possible to keep existing listings (like latest events) working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with collective.folderish, the description sounds promising though, too bad it seems not to work for you.

If I needed to solve this and it's *not* a requirement to keep the histories (workflow- & content-history), I'd go create a new folderish type with the same fields, create for each event and news an instance of the new type and copy the field-values over.

That would change the modification-date, yet could be overcome by copying the mod-date to the publication-date-field (if not used already) and do the 'Latest news/events'-listings with collections sorted by pub-date.

But if you wanted to keep histories and leave mod-date untouched, you could create a folder for each news/event-item, put the item into the folder, set the item as default-view of the folder and rename the folder to the same id as the item. That will make the folder and item appear as one item in the UI and links to the item will not break because the folder is at the destination.

I tested this with a browser-view-script. Alas, adding a folder and moving the item within one script-run does not work for reasons I couldn't track down in short time. So one needs to call the browser-view three times:

```
from Acquisition import aq_parent, aq_inner
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView


class View(BrowserView):

    report = ''

    def __call__(self):
        portal = self.context
        catalog = portal.portal_catalog
        news_items = catalog.searchResults(portal_type='News Item')
        event_items = catalog.searchResults(portal_type='Event')
        items = news_items + event_items
        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            self.processItem(item, i, len(items))
        return self.report


    def processItem(self, item, i, itemsAmount):
        item      = item.getObject()
        item_id   = item.id
        parent    = aq_parent(aq_inner(item))
        folder = None
        folder_id = item_id + '-container'


        if item_id == parent.id:

            if i == itemsAmount-1: self.report += '\
Nothing to do, all ' +  str(itemsAmount) + ' items have the same id as their parent.'


        else:
            if parent.id == folder_id:
                parent = getParent(parent)
                folder = parent[folder_id]
                folder.setDefaultPage(item_id)
                parent.manage_renameObject(folder.id, item_id)
                if i == itemsAmount-1: self.report += '\
Step 3/3: Renamed ' +  str(itemsAmount) + ' folder-ids.'

            else:
                try:
                    folder = addFolder(parent, folder_id)
                    if i == itemsAmount-1: self.report += '\
Step 1/3: Added ' +  str(itemsAmount) + ' folders.'

                    folder.setTitle(item_id) # set same title as item has
                    folder.reindexObject()
                except:
                    folder = parent[folder_id]
                try:
                    cutAndPaste(item, folder)
                    if i == itemsAmount-1: self.report += '\
Step 2/3: Moved ' +  str(itemsAmount) + ' items into folders.'
                except:
                    pass

def addFolder(parent, folder_id):
    parent.invokeFactory('Folder', folder_id)
    folder = parent[folder_id]
    folder.setTitle(folder_id)
    folder.reindexObject()
    return folder

def cutAndPaste(item, folder):
    """ Move item into folder. """
    parent = aq_parent(aq_inner(item))
    clipboard = parent.manage_cutObjects([item.id])
    folder.manage_pasteObjects(clipboard)
    folder.reindexObject()

def getParent(item):
    return aq_parent(aq_inner(item))
```

**Disclaimers:**

1. You need to do this procedure also every time a new event/news-item is created, with an event-listener.
2. It would be better to create new event-listeners for each step of the process and start the next one when the preceding step has ended.
3. The temporary-id for the folder (composed of item-id and the arbitrary suffix "-container") is assumed to not exist already within the parent of an item. Although it is very unlikely to happen, you might want to grab that exception in the script, too.

Comment: Activating in Add-ons only: collective.folderishtypes: Archetypes Default... it seems working for me now. It's nice the types are replaced - in Add new menu I have not duplicate similar content types. I must update the listings queries to include folderish objects. Maybe I will get rid of migration of old objects for the moment - I see we can edit them, too (as old non-folderish types). Without migration we can replace an old item with a new one in case we need it folderish, but most probably it's not needed for old news and events. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but based on the `collective.folderishtypes` [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.folderishtypes#how-to-migrate-non-folderishtypes-to-folderish-ones) ("How to migrate non-folderishtypes to folderish ones") you should be able to call the `@@migrate-btrees` view on your Plone site root to migrate non-folderish content types to folderish.

**Warning**: do a backup of the database before attempting the migration, and test in development environment first before applying this on production data.

Comment: 2017/11/23-14:24:52 migrating btree-based folders from <PloneSite at /mysite>:

2017/11/23-14:24:54 intermediate commit (0 objects processed, last batch in 2.336s)...

2017/11/23-14:24:54 processed 0 object(s) in 2.336s (0.968s cpu time).

I will check the docs. It's seems I have no other alternative. So I will use collective.folderishtypes. Thank you.

Comment: 0 objects processed -> old objects are not folderish.

Comment: Strange... Maybe it's a bug in `collective.folderishtypes` or I'm misunderstanding the docs. In any case it would be useful if you could create a bug report: https://github.com/collective/collective.folderishtypes/issues

So the issue gets resolved or the documentation is clarified.